# Submit doesn't fire in custom WebControl (Server Control)

Tags: c#, asp.net-webcontrol

The submit button I create doesn't fire, not even if i set a breakpoint in Visual Studio trying to debug it.

```
public class CustomControl : WebControl
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        // Submit
        var submitButton = new Button{Text = "Submit", ID = "SubmitButton"};
        submitButton.Click += new EventHandler(SubmitClick);
        Controls.Add(submitButton);

        base.Render(writer);
    }

    protected void SubmitClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("submited"));
        OnSubmit(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

It's added like this to the page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <MyControls:CustomControl runat="server" />
</form>
```

Or maybe I'm just having the wrong approach here.

Answer (score 1):

Add your button to the control inside the `Page_Init` or `Page_Load` event of the custom control instead of doing it in Render event.

Because after post back button click event would be called before the `Render` event.

Comment: Controls put in Page_Init and Page_Load wont even render i a webcontrol, or?

Answer (score 0):

Implement **INamingContainer** to activate EventHandlers

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx